# SP13: Custom Advanced Searching Web Part Options

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, search, xml, advanced-search

using SharePoint 2013 and editing advanced searching web part

Scenario: I know you can disable some of the things that appear as advanced searching options in the properties window but I want to add other options that are specific to my needs. Example if I want to remove the language section and put there team member names then as the checkboxes would be the names.  Is this possible?

I have tried to modify the xmlns file but not sure if I'm headed in the right direction.

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a web part for this. You just need a simple form that can:

1. Create a simple form that collects the information you desire
2. Create a query string with the data
3. Redirect the user to the Search Page with the Query String appended to the URL. For example by adding a button to the page.

For example:

1. Collect ContentType and Author Name
2. "ContentType=CompanyContract Author:Ruby"
3. `https://tenant/search/pages/results.aspx?k="ContentType=CompanyContract Author:Ruby"`